# Increasing counter app results in 01 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I made this simple counter app, code for html and js is below. The decrease button works fine, takes the h1 text down by 1 with each click. The reset button goes back to 0. But when I click the increase button, the text content changes from 0 to 01, then 011, then 0111, and so on. I can not figure out what the heck the problem is. I just want it to increase by 1!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <h1 id="counter">0</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="dec">Decrease</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="res">Reset</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="inc">Increase</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
const decButton = document.querySelector('#dec')
const resButton = document.querySelector('#res')
const incButton = document.querySelector('#inc')
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter')

resButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent = 0;
})

decButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent -= 1;
})

incButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent += 1;
})
```

I tried changing from arrow functions to traditional functions, I tried changing `.textContent` to `.innerText`, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script Javascript may recognize the textcontent as a string type instead of an actual int so it actually does concatenate a string rather than adding +1 to an actual int, you can try to use ParseInt in order to convert it to an actual number, after that if you want of course, you can easily convert the number to a string again.

Anyway in your code instead of

```
incButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent += 1;
})
```

you should go with something like:

```
decButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent = parseInt(counter.textContent) + 1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with the increase button in your JavaScript code is related to the way JavaScript handles the `+=` operator with strings. The `counter.textContent` property is a string, not a number, so when you use `+= 1`, JavaScript performs string concatenation instead of arithmetic addition.

To fix this, you should explicitly convert `counter.textContent` to a number before performing the addition. You can use the `Number()` function for this conversion. Here's the corrected code for the increase button event listener:

```js
incButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) + 1;
});
```

With this change, `counter.textContent` will be converted to a number before 1 is added to it, and the result will then be converted back to a string to be displayed. This should resolve the issue and make the counter increase by 1 each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I don't understand though, why I dont need to do the same with -=

Answer (score 0):

counter.textContent  returns string, so adding number to it will result in string concat..

```
decButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent = +counter.textContent - 1;
})

incButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.textContent =  +counter.textContent + 1
})
```